# chart js change chart on radio button and animate again

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I am not sure why won't change on radio button change and how can I animate again that chart...

full code:
[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfyuwmyy/)

```
<div class="box">
<form id='group'>
   <label>
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="group1" class="trigger" data-rel="chart-item1" /> Item 1
    </label>
    <label>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" class="trigger" data-rel="chart-item2" /> Item 2
    </label>
 </form>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: You can call `update` function on your declared chart variable e.g. `myChart.update();`

Comment: but it won't change on radio button selection... What should I change there?

Comment: `$("#group input[type=radio]").on('change', function(){ myChart.update(); });`

Comment: hmmm it doesn't work, if I add it at the end `$(".chart-item2").on('change', function(){ m.update(); });` nothing happens even #group input doesn't work

Comment: `chart-item2` is not a class so obviously it would not work. You can try `$(".trigger").on('change', function(){ m.update(); });` as your radios have `trigger` class. If even that does not work, please add an alert/console statement inside your `change` handler to see that at least the change event fires.

Comment: ohh sorry about that... event fires but nothing changes on front end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117339/discussion-between-mohit-bhardwaj-and-morpheus).

Comment: Any other ideas? Anyone?

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: Hey I've been trying to contact you in that chat but you are not there, why? You can check [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfyuwmyy/1/)  for yourself....  Thanks

Comment: May be because I was offline then. The fiddle shows error. You have not included the ChartJS library.

Comment: If I didn't include it, how come that it draws chart? It is included... Check again please... Something else is the problem...